# Script writing for a random number generator with if and else condition

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have wrote 2 scripts thanks for everybody for helping me in that.

Now I want to write a script to run these 2 scripts randomly with a ratio of 1:4. 
My files are named 1.sh and 2.sh.

I want to generate a number from 1 to 4, and then to use the if condition so that if the number generated is 1 then run 1.sh else run 2.sh. I wrote the below script but it is not working, I think there is something wrong in the if condition line, can you please help me to fix this problem.

```
va1=$((1 + RANDOM % 4))
if va1= 1 ; then bash 1.sh; else bash 2.sh; fi
```

Finally I want to run this script 4500 times. So I will save this script as random.sh

and then I will write in the terminal :

```
for i in {1..4500}; do bash random.sh; done
```

Please help me to write the random.sh script because there is something missing in my if condition line and hence it does not work.
Is it correct the line I wrote to run the script 4500 times ?.
Finally is it possible to run a script which in turn will run 2 scripts all of them are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it :)

what comes after # is the clarification

```
va1=$((1 + RANDOM % 2497))
#I generate a random number from 1 to 2497
if [ $va1 -gt 29 ]       
#If the generated number is greater than 29
then
       bash C60.sh 
# then run the script C60.sh
else
       bash TAPC.sh 
#If any number less than 29 or 29 itself then run TAPC.sh
fi
#end of the if statement
```

I changed the numbers from the question itself but you can apply any numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Run 4500 iterations with 1 in 4 probability:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A a=()

b=4500
for ((c=1; c<$b; c++)); do
    (($RANDOM < 8192)) && ((a[if]++)) || ((a[else]++))
done

for d in if else; do
    LC_ALL=C printf "%4s ~ %0.2f%%\n" \
    $d $(bc -l <<< "100 / ($b / ${a[$d]})")
done
```